# convert to number (string) by keeping the same number

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, number-formatting

I have a string like € 1.580 (1580 €). 
By doing the following statement the number become:

```
select to_number(SUBSTR(col1,2)) from TAB1 where riga = 2;
Number Result: 1.58
```

I want to keep the 0 because the real number is 1580 and I want to display 1.580. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a number?

Comment: Your description is confusing. Quote a) `I have a string like € 1.580 (1580 €).` Is it `€ 1.580` or is it `1580 €`?   b)  `the real number is 1580  and I want to display 1.580`. Whatta, Whatta? So what exactly is it you have and what you want it to convert into (desired result)?

Comment: The string is € 1.580 (which is 1580€ and not 1.58€). As result of to_number, I want 1.580

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options using the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` and `NLS_CURRENCY` options with `TO_NUMBER`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d6920/17)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  col1 VARCHAR2( 200 )
);

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES ( '€ 1.580' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
        SUBSTR( col1, 2 ),
         '999G999',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''
       ) AS value1,
       TO_NUMBER(
         REPLACE( col1, ' ' ),
         'L999G999',
         'NLS_CURRENCY=''€'' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''
       ) AS value2
FROM   tab1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d6920/17/0)**:

```
| VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
|--------|--------|
|   1580 |   1580 |
```

If you want to re-format it as a string then, just use `TO_CHAR` again:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_NUMBER(
           REPLACE( col1, ' ' ),
           'L999G999',
           'NLS_CURRENCY=''€'' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''
         ),
         'FM999G999',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''
       )AS value2
FROM   tab1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d6920/17/1)**:

```
| VALUE2 |
|--------|
|  1.580 |
```

But you ought to be storing the value as a number and whenever you want to format it as a currency then just use `TO_CHAR( value, 'L999G999' )` with the appropriate NLS options and do **NOT** store it as a formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

if you have fixed number of digit then you need to use like this

```
select Convert(numeric(18,3),to_number(SUBSTR(col1,2))) from TAB1 where riga = 2;

Number Result: 1.580
```

Or

```
you can put in your to_number function of returns with numeric(18,3)
```